# How to understand complex lists in python

Tags: python

Sorry this will be a very basic question, I am learning python.

I went through a coding exercise to calculate bmi and went for a straightforward way:

```
def bmi(weight, height):
    bmi = weight / height ** 2
    if bmi <= 18.5:
        return "Underweight"
    elif bmi <= 25:
        return "Normal"
    elif bmi <= 30:
        return "Overweight"
    else:
        return "Obese"
```

However, in the exercise solutions I also see this one:

```
def bmi(weight, height):
    b = weight / height ** 2
    return ['Underweight', 'Normal', 'Overweight', 'Obese'][(b > 30) + (b > 25) + (b > 18.5)]
```

I want to understand what this double/back-to-back list is where they've got [items][conditions] but I can't find the name of it to learn about it - what is the name for this? Is it a part of list comprehensions?

Comment: `(b > 30) + (b > 25) + (b > 18.5)` is not a list; it is the index for the preceding list.

Comment: Conditions like `(b > 30)` are booleans (true/false), but in the presence of mathematical operators they get casted to integers (1/0) and here they get added up. In the end you get something like `['Underweight', 'Normal', 'Overweight', 'Obese'][2]` which becomes "Overweight"

Comment: Run `True + False`, `int(True)` and `int(False)` and you'll understand

Comment: Note that your code is quite much more explicit, it should be preferred!

Comment: Thank you for all your help this is clear to me now, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

observe this line carefully

```py
['Underweight', 'Normal', 'Overweight', 'Obese'][(b > 30) + (b > 25) + (b > 18.5)]
```

Above is line is actually list indexing  `[(b > 30) + (b > 25) + (b > 18.5)]` this gives the index of the list `['Underweight', 'Normal', 'Overweight', 'Obese']`. Let us say b > 30 then it satisfies all the three conditions **(b > 30) + (b > 25) + (b > 18.5)** the equivalent boolean value of each condition is 1 making the sum 3 and returns index 3 which is **Obese**. Similarly it works for other conditions.

Comment: Basic idea is to reach a particular state it should satisfy all the above states , to be obese it should cross Underweight and Normal, cumulative boolean value acts as index for each result.